# Can I 'extend' jQuery object with a prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend, prototypal-inheritance

I have a multistep form plugin on my site and it has multicontrol.prototype that holds functions for next and previous buttons.

Is it possible to extend e.g. $('.button.prev') with this multicontrol prototype? So that I could assign similar functionality to any element and call e.g. $('.button').previous();

Comment: Sure, `$.fn.previous = function(...) {... }` aka a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a plugin scheme that allows you to extend a jQuery object with new methods.  There's a tutorial [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Here's a very simple example from that tutorial:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    return this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

Internally, `$.fn` is a prototype object that is used by new jQuery objects so adding a property to it, adds a method to all jQuery objects.

By convention, most jQuery plugin methods should return the jQuery object to enable chaining.  And, if you have to process individual DOM nodes, then you should probably iterate `this.each()` in the plug-in method so that it works on a collection of DOM nodes, not just a single node.  Most jQuery methods already do this themselves.

Comment: Okay, but if I have this multicontrol.prototype should I use it e.g. `$.fn.multicontrol = multicontrol.prototype;` What I'm looking for is that can I 'cast' jquery object as multicontrol.prototype?